# Could not load requested file in assets folder

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I can not load my assets folder that is outside my application / view folder

```
<?php $this->load->view('assets/parts/webpage/header'); ?>
```

My directory is like this

> Assets > parts > webpage > header

But on my screen this appears

```
Unable to load the requested file: /assets/parts/webpage/header.php
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load assets folder outside of application then you have to set view directory in index.php file.
$view_folder = '';